# Use Java Stream to filter list based on values from second list

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, filtering

I'm trying to Filter a list of objects based on values from second list.

## List A:

```
[
   {
      "id":"12345",
      "name":"nameOfItem",
      "description":"descriptionOfItem"
   },
   {
      "id":"34567",
      "name":"nameOfItem",
      "description":"descriptionOfItem"
   },
   {
      "id":"56789",
      "name":"nameOfItem",
      "description":"descriptionOfItem"
   }
]
```

## List B:

```
["12345", "56789"]
```

Now i want to remove the item of List A with IDs available in List B.

Im trying to use JavaStream but can't understand the syntax and i'm trying ForEach loop but its not working properly.

I've done something similar in Swift as following.

```
            if let allModOptions = allModifersList?.first?.options {
                let excludedIDs = pObj?.excluded_ids
                if excludedIDs!.count > 0 {
                   let allowedOptions = allModOptions
                   ->>>>    **.filter{ !excludedIDs!.contains($0.id!)}** <<<<-
                        .filter{c in c.deleted_at == nil}.sorted {
                        $0.index ?? 0 < $1.index ?? 0
                       }
                
                    allModsList?.first?.options = allowedOptions
                
                }
               modisList.append(contentsOf: allModsList!)
            }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please post your code and explain your issues with it

Comment: *m trying to use JavaStream ...* - It's a very basic problem. Post your code so that we can understand where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I've added my one line solution from Swift but can't understand Java Stream syntax for the same.

Comment: List B should be a `Set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use filter on main collection and !contains on List collection

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {
    static class Element {
        int id;
        String name;
        String description;

        public Element(int id, String name, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Element{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
           new Element(12345, "nameofitem", "asdfafd"),
           new Element(34567, "nameofitem", "asdfafd"),
           new Element(56789, "nameofitem", "asdfafd")
        ));
        List<Integer> filterNot = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(12345, 56789));
        List<Element> result = elements.stream().filter(item -> !filterNot.contains(item.id)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked. this bit i  was missing -> !filterNot.contains(item.id)

Answer (score 1):

- If I understand correctly, you are given the following information:

  - a class with 3 fields: `id`, `name`, `description`. Lets call this class `Item`.
  - a list of ids of `Item`s which should be removed from `List A`. Lets call this list, `idsOfItemsToRemove`.
  - a list of all `Item`s to evaluate
  - an expected list; a list of `Item`s which do not contain any value present in `idsOfItemsToRemove`.
- If the above assumptions are true, then the code snippet below should be indicative of what you are seeking to do.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // given
    Integer idOfItemToBeRemoved1 = 12345;
    Integer idOfItemToBeRemoved2 = 56789;
    Item itemExpectedToBeDeleted1 = new Item(idOfItemToBeRemoved1, "nameOfItem", "descriptionOfItem");
    Item itemExpectedToBeDeleted2 = new Item(idOfItemToBeRemoved2, "nameOfItem", "descriptionOfItem");
    Item itemExpectedToBeRetained1 = new Item(34567, "nameOfItem", "descriptionOfItem");
    Item itemExpectedToBeRetained2 = new Item(98756, "nameOfItem", "descriptionOfItem");


    List<Integer> idsOfItemsToRemove = Arrays.asList(
            idOfItemToBeRemoved1,
            idOfItemToBeRemoved2);

    List<Item> listOfItems = Arrays.asList(
            itemExpectedToBeDeleted1,
            itemExpectedToBeDeleted2,
            itemExpectedToBeRetained1,
            itemExpectedToBeRetained2);

    List<Item> expectedList = Arrays.asList(
            itemExpectedToBeRetained1,
            itemExpectedToBeRetained2);

    // when
    List<Item> actualList = listOfItems
            .stream()
            .filter(item -> !idsOfItemsToRemove.contains(item.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // then
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
}
```

This code has also been `push`ed to Github.

> `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Git-Leon/stackoverflow-answers/master/javastreamfilter/`